# How to uninstall OpenLDAP in RedHat?

Tags: linux, rhel, ldap, openldap, uninstall

I have installed OpenLDAP with yum, but I have accidentally deleted some of the config files. I am not able to recover them. I want to uninstall it. I tried the following command but it ends with an error:

```
--> Processing Dependency: PackageKit-glib = 0.5.8-20.el6 for package: PackageKit-gtk-module-0.5.8-20.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package PackageKit-device-rebind.x86_64 0:0.5.8-20.el6 will be erased
---> Package PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin.x86_64 0:0.5.8-20.el6 will be erased
---> Package PackageKit-gtk-module.x86_64 0:0.5.8-20.el6 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can someone please tell how to uninstall it properly so I can install it again and make the config changes?

[image]

Comment: Where is the command. It looks like you remove `yum` with `yum`  (did you cut and paste a command and pasted it twice before hitting return?)

Comment: # yum remove openldap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make a backup of the configuration and :

```
yum remove openldap
rpm -e openldap.package_name
yum install openldap
```

And copy your configuration files back

Comment: I think u did not check my question in detail

Comment: Your configuration files have not been removed if you did only a yum remove. If you've errors while trying to install openldap back as "no such files or directory" it can mean that openldap as not been removed properly. Those commands stand to remove it properly and install it again. So far if your configuration disappeared from the disk you'd check if you have any backup.

Comment: These error when i am trying to run 
'yum remove openldap'
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]

Comment: Can you try to reinstall libldap only?

Comment: yum install libldap end with the above error

Comment: What's your OS version?

Comment: Red Hat enterprises Linux Server Releases6.3(Santiago)

Comment: Can you check if the rpm is still in the cache : `find /var/cache -name libldap*.rpm` if yes try a rpm -ivh on it otherwise [link](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/limit/6/srodzaj/1/dl/40/search/libldap-2.4.so.2/field[]/1/field[]/2) and do the same

Comment: Its not in cache and just browsed the link u provided it have around 500+ result

Comment: Try with for find *ldap* . I can give you the link to the rpm but I need a u name -a pls

Comment: find: `ldap': No such file or directory

But still i am able to start or stop openldap  and i did not get  " I can give you the link to the rpm but I need a u name -a pls "
"

Comment: `find / -name *ldap*.rpm` and `uname -a`

Comment: for first one no output and second one "Linux mdfdevapp2 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
"

Comment: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25555224/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/openldap-2.4.23-34.el6_5.1.i686.rpm.html may help

Comment: SO if i will download rpm and install it again it will download dependency as well?

Comment: The openldap shall include the dependency broken. Could you try the latest command before download it from the site `yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp libldap` and `rpm -ivh /tmp/package_name`

Comment: Every yum command end with `yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp libldap`
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]

Comment: Thanks i have rum rpms of ldap now yum command also working

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to remove the wrong package.

openldap provides only the library files **(libldap, liblber, etc.)** and it's required by pretty much everything on the system. So when you try to remove it yum goes through the list of dependencies which is pretty much all of it.

The configuration files that you deleted are part of the openldap-servers package (and possibly openldap-clients package). You can remove them as usual: `yum remove openldap-servers`.

You can check to which package the files belong to by running `yum provides <full path or */file>` ex.  `yum provides /etc/openldap/slapd.d`  or `yum provides */ldap.conf`

Comment: Now for every command i am getting below exception
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]

Comment: Well, it seems you have deleted the openldap package (or part of it - definitely the lib), so you'll have to find the package for your system and installed it manually. yum will not work, rpm however it will. I'm not sure what system you are running (version 2.4.23 is outdated for rhel6/7 - it's using vers 2.4.39). If it's a rhel/centos 6 download the latest and install: wget ftp://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openldap-2.4.39-8.el6.x86_64.rpm && rpm -ivh openldap-2.4.39-6.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I am using    
Red Hat enterprises Linux Server Releases6.3(Santiago) –

Comment: You'll need access to redhat network (rhn.redhat.com) to download the package manually (yumdownloader will not work). If you don't have access you can download the equivalent centos package (it will work) but if you don't want to upgrade to latest version (2.4.39) you'll need to find a repository which keeps older versions of packages (check http://vault.centos.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reinstall` to reinstall the OpenLDAP package:

```
# yum reinstall openldap
```

That should reinstall the default configuration files and leave you with a fresh installation.

Comment: There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]

Comment: @LinuxBegineer You've deleted parts of OpenLDAP, which now prevents `yum` from running. The solution is to download the OpenLDAP RPM for RHEL 6 and install that manually using `rpm`. That should fix `yum`.

Comment: No i accidentally deleted only config file which is inside /etc/openldap/slapd.d/* nothing else

Comment: @LinuxBegineer Ok. Well, the same suggestion applies - download the OpenLDAP RPM for RHEL6 and reinstall it using `rpm`.